# WooCommerce display order product name in my account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce 2.0 and I would like to retrieve and display the ordered product name in the myaccount.php page, alongside the order number.

So if this is the default display in myaccount.php:

```
ORDER   DATE    STATUS  TOTAL   ACTIONS LICENSING
#521    August 19, 2014 Completed   $99.99 for 1 item   VIEW
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
ORDER               DATE    STATUS  TOTAL   ACTIONS LICENSING
#521-ProductName    August 19, 2014 Completed   $99.99 for 1 item   VIEW
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to retrieve the order product name? I am confused on how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it after making some changes in your my-orders.php

you need my-orders.php. Place a copy in your theme folder to make it update proof.

```
//Add the following code  in the customer_order loop

foreach($order->get_items() as $item) {
    $product_name = $item['name'];

}

<?php echo $product_name;?> //echo product name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'shop_order',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
  'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

$customer_orders = $my_query->posts;

foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {
 $order = new WC_Order();

 $order->populate($customer_order);
 $orderdata = (array) $order;

 // $orderdata Array will have Information. for e.g Shippin firstname, Lastname, Address ... and MUCH more.... Just enjoy!
}
```

And in order to get more details of the order you can use the below code.

Assuming $post->ID is the id of the product you want to display the orders containing, this is what you need:

```
$products = array();
foreach (get_posts('post_type=shop_order&numberposts=-1&post_status=publish') as $order) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order->ID);
    foreach($order->get_items('line_item') as $item) {
        $product_id = (!empty($item['variation_id'])) ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'];
        $products[] = $product_id;
    }
    if (in_array($post->ID,$products)) {
        echo 'Status: '.$order->order_status;                         
        echo '<br>Date  : '.$order->order_date;                           
        echo '<br>Email  : '.$order->billing_email; 
    }   
}
```