# How to loop product name and photos in my-orders.php page for recent orders?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I have to add product name and thumbnail to my recent orders page. I don't know how to loop them if there are more than one product in one order.

*(Dead image link removed)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Just set the loop for products names, but i haven't test it. You will have to search for thumbnails (see the link at the end).

For the products loop, i have use the code from Sandeep Kumar: [WooCommerce display order product name in my account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439516/woocommerce-display-order-product-name-in-my-account)

```
foreach($order->get_items() as $item) {
    $product_name = $item['name'];
}
```

The code of your custom template is here below:

```css
.my_product_name {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<?php
/**
 * My Orders
 *
 * Shows recent orders on the account page
 *
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.3.10
 */
 
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
 
$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
) ) );
 
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
 
if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>
 
    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', __( 'Recent Orders', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></h2>
 
    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders">
 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="order-number"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-date"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="shipping-name"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Customer name', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="products-names"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Products names', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-status"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-total"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                <th class="order-actions">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 
        <tbody><?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
                $order->populate( $customer_order );
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
 
                ?><tr class="order">
                    <td class="order-number" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Order Number', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                            <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-date" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>
                    </td>
                    <td class="shipping-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Customer name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <span><?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'billing_first_name', $user_id ).' '.get_the_author_meta( 'billing_last_name', $user_id ); ?></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="products-names" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Products names', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                    <?php 
                        foreach($order->get_items() as $item) {
                            $product_name = $item['name'];
                    ?>
                        <span class="my_product_name"><?php echo $product_name; ?></span>
                     <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-status" data-title="<?php _e( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap;">
                        <?php
                        if($order->get_status()=='completed')
                        {
                            echo 'Dispatched';
                        }
                        else{
                         echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );
                         }
                          ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-total" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="order-actions">
                        <?php
                            $actions = array();
 
                            if ( in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                $actions['pay'] = array(
                                    'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                    'name' => __( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' )
                                );
                            }
 
                            if ( in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                $actions['cancel'] = array(
                                    'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                    'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' )
                                );
                            }
 
                            $actions['view'] = array(
                                'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                'name' => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' )
                            );
 
                            $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order );
 
                            if ( $actions ) {
                                foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr><?php
            }
        ?></tbody>
 
    </table>
 
<?php endif; ?>
```

For your products thumbnails, please have a look to this thread with the solution of helgatheviking: [Echo woocommerce product thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179558/echo-woocommerce-product-thumbnail)